# Simplicial set construction of the classifying space

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, simplicial-stuff

What would be the best book, article, or otherwise to reference for the specific construction of the classifying space for a discrete group $G$ which goes as follows?:

- Regard $G$ as a category with one object whose morphisms are the elements of $G$.
- Construct the simplicial sets $NG$ (i.e., the nerve of $G$) and $\mathcal{E}G$ (unsure if there's a standard notation; I mean that $\mathcal{E}G_n$ should be $G^{n+1}$ with face maps given by deletion and degeneracy maps given by repetition).
- Take the geometric realizations $BG$ of $NG$ and $EG$ of $\mathcal{E}G$; then $BG$ is the classifying space with universal cover $EG$.

As far as I know, this is a fairly standard construction (although perhaps not *the* standard one). I'm just wondering about the best place to use as a reference for it.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear this is not "the" standard construction. What have you seen described so?

Comment: I was under the impression 'the' standard construction was using fibers, as in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. Possibly that's just where I saw it first, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that's called the Milgram bar construction:

- R.J. Milgram, *The bar construction and abelian $H$-spaces*, Illinois J. Math. 11 (1967), 242-250.

Answer (score 5):

I know this description from following paper of Segal. He doesn't mention Milgram there, but relates it to Milnor's join construction. Also, $G$ is allowed to be any topological group, no need for discreteness!

*Segal, Graeme*, [**Classifying spaces and spectral sequences**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02684591), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 34, 105-112 (1968). [ZBL0199.26404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0199.26404).

Comment: Well, it's a reasonable construction if the topological group is well-pointed. If it fails to be, then the fat geometric realisation is the right construction, I believe.